# How to make Python Chatbot to call specific function?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, chatbot

I made chatbot in Python with a help of Keras lib. My chatbot works great but now I want to add a feature so that it can tell what day, time, weather is it, for example:

```
me: what time is it?
bot: its 12:35
```

Data that I used is `csv` format where features are questions and answers are labels.
My model is predicting answer based on user question input.

For example, for this set of questions:

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = ["what's the time", "whats the time?", "what time is it?",
         "today is what day?", "what day is today", "what day is it?",
         "what is the temperature", "how is the weather?"]

list2 = ["it is time.time()", "it is time.time()", "it is time.time()",
         "today is get_day()", "today is get_day()", "today is get_day()",
         "the weather is get_weather()", "the weather is get_weather()"]

df = pd.DataFrame()

df["question"] = list1
df["answer"] = list2

                  question                        answer
0          what's the time             it is time.time()
1          whats the time?             it is time.time()
2         what time is it?             it is time.time()
3       today is what day?            today is get_day()
4        what day is today            today is get_day()
5          what day is it?            today is get_day()
6  what is the temperature  the weather is get_weather()
7      how is the weather?  the weather is get_weather()
```

The answer / label should be: `"It is " + time.time()`

But I can't pass `"It is " + time.time()` as a label because its not string or numeric value.

I know that i can get time in Python like `time.time()` but how can I add that function to be my answer. My answers need to be numeric values (because I'm passing them into ML model) so I cant write `"time is"+time.time()`. Is there a way to do this, to store function in json file or csv file and make ML model. I can change my data to be JSON format if that helps.

PS
I'm planning to make a lot of functions that will be predicted so simple solutions such as:

```
if answer == 'time':
   print(time.time())
```

Does not work for me. I would like to automate this

Comment: you're feeding the output of a chatbot into a machine learning model? can you explain why that is?

Comment: Well I need to have features and results. I'm using classification to determinate answer based on the input.

Comment: but the bot is providing the answers?

Comment: i guess i don't understand how machine learning would predict the response to "what time is it?" and so the premise of the question is completely unclear

Comment: Yes. I have dataset with questions and answers. Model is learning based on that. Now I want to add set of questions like "what time is it", "how much time is it"... etc. and answer should be "its "+time.time(). But I cant pass something like that to my model

Comment: if the user asks for the time, the predictor should return some canned response that your code can catch and replace with `time.time()`

Comment: yes, something like that. Can you show me how to do that?

Comment: `if text_out == 'time question': return "time is: "+ time.time()`

Comment: And what If my chatbot has more than 50 questions that require calling some kind of function, then I cant do IF statement for all of them. Is there a way to store function inside a json file or csv or something like that

Comment: you only need to check for the time result (based on what you've described here)